# Sharing SXA Placeholder Settings over sites

Tags: sxa, placeholders

I would like to have all new SXA sites that are created in my environment to start with the same set of placeholder settings. The sites will share a "base" site that is used to define the partial and page designs - but I understood that placeholder settings are not among the things that get shared...

So a copy would be good enough for me. But what would be the easiest way to achieve this? Do I need to add them to the scaffolding? I guess so - but how? I could add the items with the `AddItem` but for setting the actual values that seems not the best option. It seems possible with the "Fields", but putting a list of guids in there just doesn't feel right.

Anyone done this before? Or an example from sxa ootb that I can use?

Comment: Have you considered creating a branch template with the items that you want? Then in the scaffolding you can reference the branch template.

Comment: That actually sounds like a good idea. I completely forgot I could do that.. probably because I was not seeing them in a folder. Not my day :(  You can add it as answer if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, SXA has a scaffolding feature that helps to speed up new tenant/site creation.

For example, the Page Content feature has the following:

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Page Content`

[image: Scaffolding screenshot]

Each of the items with the plus icon (AddItem template) have a way for you to create items in the tree. You may test out using a branch template in your own custom section outside of the Experience Accelerator node to help create the custom tree for placeholders.